# div css fix for 100% floating divs sum

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How can i fix the problem that makes IE drop last div?

```
<div>
 <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width:50%;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
</div>
```

this it should be correct, but on older IE it makes last div go on a new line

Comment: use this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hy3yb/3/) its helpful for you.

Comment: This seems to be not the complete code because without height to the div elements they are not visible. post your complete code or relevant code and also try to make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 2):

set below css in your stylesheet

```
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

It has some padding and margin by default which need to be reset to 0.

Comment: sorry did not specify but it does with padding and margin equal zero too

Comment: what IE version are you talking about?? Any specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 100%;">
  <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
  <div style="float:left; width:50%;"></div>
  <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="padding:0;margin:0;">
 <div style="float:left;height:200px; width:25%;background:blue;">text</div>
 <div style="float:left;height:200px; width:50%;background:yellow;">text</div>
 <div style="float:left;height:200px; width:25%;background:green;">text</div>
</div>
```

Here is Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XabvC/

And are you sure your browser zoom value. It should be 100%. If you use IE 10, you should set  Browser mode and Document mode on developer tools (F12)

Answer (score 0):

there could be a space being displayed in a collapsed form try

```
<div  style="font-size:0px">
 <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width:50%;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width:25%;"></div>
</div>
```